# Tengo un problema, me sale java.lang.NumberFormatException al ejecutar mi programa

Tags: java, archivo

Necesito hacer una estadística con una información en un archivo [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) son 148.119 datos pero al compilar mi código me sale un `NumberFormatException` trate de hacer la excepción pero en vez de hacer la operación me envía el mensaje de error.

lo ensaye con una  menor cantidad de datos y el código se ejecuta sin ningún problema, pero al colocar el archivo que necesito manipular, sigue con ese error.

Código

```
boolean error = false;
        try {
            dat = new FileReader("MFPT_GEIH_2015.csv");
        } catch (IOException obj) {
            error = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al tratar de abrir el archivo.");
        }
        if (!error) {
            String linea = "";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(dat);
            String tokens[];
            try {
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    tokens = linea.split(";");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]); // aquí me marca la excepción
                        if (i == 1) {
                            suma = op + 1;
                            System.out.println(suma + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException obj) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al tratar de leer el archivo.");
            }
            try {
                dat.close();
            } catch (IOException obj) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al tratar de cerrar el archivo.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ese error se produce porque una de las cadenas que se intenta convertir a `long` no contiene un número válido, puede ser que tenga comas,  puntos, espacios o algo que no sea un número. Revisa el formato de los datos de entrada.

Comment: Revise el archivo y quite todo los datos que no son numéricos pero aun me sale esa excepción. Hice una prueba, borrando mas de la mitad de los datos y me hace la conversión, pero al volver a colocar todos me sale lo mismo.

Comment: Puedes colocar la línea `op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]); ` en un `try/catch` y en el `catch` hacer un `System.out.println(tokens[i]); ` para saber el formato de la cadena que da error ?

Comment: muevo op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]); y el System.out.println(tokens[i]); con los try/catch que tengo en el código o hago otro try/catch  para la conversión y el System? y te muestro lo que me sale ?

Comment: catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    }
   } // Creo que entendí así  use la excepción NumberFormatException  o sigo unsadon el  IOException? al compilar me salio  esto :  ï»¿3704584

Comment: Reemplaza la línea actual : `op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]);` por el siguiente código: try {  op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]); } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(tokens[i]); }  Debe quedar así: https://gist.github.com/crrlos/6e270ee8fba72d63b0cb767d16ab414d

Comment: Ya lo remplace y se ejecuta correctamente, me faltaba agregar otra excepción, muchas gracias.

Comment: Noo . Alto, eso es para identificar qué produce el error y arreglarlo. Puedes ver la cadena que se imprime cuando se producen los errores? Para eso se agregó el try catch, para depurar el archivo de texto y encontrar los datos que causan el fallo.

Comment: Lo organice así como me mostrarte y al compilar ya me aparece todos los datos con la suma que le tengo y cambien la posición en el arreglo  y me da bien los datos, muestra así como lo mencionas en el comentario.

Comment: Creo que me confundí. Solo quiero confirmar el `System.out.println(tokens[i]); ` de la excepción imprimió algún dato en la consola?

Comment: Quite el System donde muestra la suma y al compilar el System.out.println(tokens[i]); me aparece esto: ï»¿3704584

Comment: Entonces sigues el error, lo siento, aun me falta experiencia en programación, aun estoy en 3ser semestre 

Comment: Bien, entonces puedes buscar ese dato en el archivo csv y corregirlo ahí para que el archivo tenga un formato correcto.  La excepción te servirá únicamente para que el programa no falle en su tarea, así cuando se produzca un `NumberFormatException` se le informará al usuario que el archivo tiene datos con formato no válido y de ser posible se le puede mostrar cúal es el dato incorrecto para que lo corrija.

Comment: Modifique el archivo y  ya  me aparece unos datos en el arreglo

Answer (score 0):

El error que se presenta se debe a que el valor que tratas de convertir a `Long` no es numérico.

Veamos el siguiente ejemplo.

```
    String str="  12 ";
    int numero;
        try{
            numero=Integer.parseInt(str);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("No es un número");
        }
```

En el caso de que el string str contenga caracteres no numéricos como es éste el caso, el número 12 está acompañado de espacios en blanco, se produce una excepción del tipo `NumberFormatException` que es capturada y se imprime el mensaje

> No es un número

Verifica en el error devuelto esta línea:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
```

Ahí te dirá cual es valor que no se puede convertir, ahora bien si en el error no se muestra esa línea, te recomiendo que pongas un `try/catch` para poder ver cual es valor que no puedes parsear.

```
        try{
             op = Long.parseLong(tokens[i]); 
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("El error es provocado por : "+tokens[i]);
        }
```